# Performing "Suggested Edits" with an reputation score below 2k?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just saw that some users (see first screenshot) can do "Suggested Edits" with an reputation score below 2k, while I seamed to need an reputation score with 2k (see 2nd screenshot). Did I found a bug or is that supposed to be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: _Aside:_ What tool are you using to create your frilly "cut-out" screenshots?

Comment: They where created with "[TechSmith - Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [user](https://serverfault.com/users/385555/bird) in question [approved](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/295575) another user's suggested edit to their own [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/814752/htaccess-replace-part-of-url-based-on-condition). Anyone can approve or reject suggested edits to their own posts, regardless of reputation. This also happens to complete the associated review task, if one is outstanding, and this causes the user to be awarded the badge.